# UIKeyboard Notification.userInfo Key bug in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, scrollview

```
  @objc func keyboardWasShown(_ notification:NSNotification)  {

    var userinfo = notification.userInfo!

    let kbSize:NSValue =  userinfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue

    let kbRectSize = kbSize.cgRectValue

    let edgeInsects = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0,kbRectSize.height + 10, 0)

    self.scrollView.contentInset = edgeInsects
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = edgeInsects



    // active text field

    var aRect:CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= kbRectSize.height


    if(!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin)){
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
        aRect = CGRect.zero
    }
}
```

The scrollview will scroll for first time as intended and then becomes unresponsive. 
The code was working fine until Xcode 8.3 without any issues.

please confirm whether it's a bug or not and how to circumvent it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                    // ==== solution  =====//
          // ==== USE UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey ===

    // as UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey return height as  0 for some 
      //reason on second call onwards , some weird bug indeed.


    var userinfo = notification.userInfo!

                        // === bug fix =====
    let kbSize:NSValue =  userinfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue

    let kbRectSize = kbSize.cgRectValue

    let edgeInsects = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0,kbRectSize.height + 10, 0)

    self.scrollView.contentInset = edgeInsects
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = edgeInsects


    // active text field

    var aRect:CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= kbRectSize.height

    if(!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin)){
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
        aRect = CGRect.zero
    }
```

Solution Found , in Xcode 9, there seems to be some change in key - value pairs of Keyboard notification userInfo dictionary.

Use UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey instead  of UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey,

As  Value for UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey for some reason does not return the proper size of the keyboard on second call onwards.

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same issue and by doing some changes it is working fine. In your scenario try below code and see if it works:

```
@objc func keyboardWasShown(_ notification:NSNotification)  {

  var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 260

  var userinfo = notification.userInfo!

  let keyboardSize = (userinfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size

  if keyboardSize!.height > 10.0{
      keyboardHeight = keyboardSize!.height
  }

  let edgeInsects = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardHeight + 10, 0)

  self.scrollView.contentInset = edgeInsects
  self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = edgeInsects

  // active text field

  var aRect:CGRect = self.view.frame
  aRect.size.height -= kbRectSize.height

  if(!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin)){
      scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
      scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
      aRect = CGRect.zero
  }
}
```

I have used below code in my project for sign up screen and it is working perfectly fine:

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification){
    //Need to calculate keyboard exact size due to Apple suggestions
    var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 260

    self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true

    var info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
    if keyboardSize!.height > 10.0{
        keyboardHeight = keyboardSize!.height
    }

    let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0)

    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardHeight

    if let activeField = self.activeField {
        if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin)){
            self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification){
    //Once keyboard disappears, restore original positions

    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

}
```

Just try and debug with some more changes according to your requirements. Hope it works.